# Research about Convex Kernels

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, online-resources

I am currently doing research in generalizing the concept of a convex kernel.  I would appreciate any links or resources pertaining to current research and basic results about convex kernels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you already have: Sparks, *Characterization of the Generalized Convex Kernel*, Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society, Vol. 27, No. 3, Mar., 1971, 563-65. It's old but a good jumping-off point and you could check subsequent references to it?